# insert image path into database in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to insert the image into an Image folder and add the image path into database using entity framework.My Model is,

```
public class Orphan
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public bool Disable { get; set; }
        public DateTime JoinedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? LeaveDate { get; set; }
        public Carer Carer { get; set; }
        public string CarerName { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }


    }
```

THis is the view model,

```
public  partial class OrphanViewModel
        {
            [Required]
            [DisplayName("First Name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [DisplayName("Last Name")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public int Age { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string Gender { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public bool Disable { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string CarerName { get; set; }
            public string ImagePath { get; set; }
            public HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile { get; set; }
        }
```

This is the view of imagepath.

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="file" name="ImageFile" required />
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the controller

```
[HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(OrphanViewModel ovm)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ovm.ImageFile.FileName);           

string extension = Path.GetExtension(ovm.ImageFile.FileName);
            fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + extension;
            ovm.ImagePath = "~/Image/" + fileName;
            fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), fileName);
            ovm.ImageFile.SaveAs(fileName);

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Orphans.Add(new Orphan()
                {
                    FirstName = ovm.FirstName,
                    LastName = ovm.LastName,
                    Age = ovm.Age,
                    Gender = ovm.Gender,
                    Disable = ovm.Disable,
                    JoinedDate = DateTime.Now,
                    CarerName = ovm.CarerName,
                    ImagePath = ovm.ImagePath
                });
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(ovm);
        }
```

So the problem i am facing is here it says in ovm.ImageFile {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}.HELP

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ovm.ImageFile.FileName);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define form content type in frontend - **enctype="multipart/form-data"**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/ActionPath">
```

Comment: How can i forget that ..Thanks :)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if your problem is resolved @sres